# how i make new array to use two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
 arr1 = [
    {
      nodeId: 1,
      xvalue: 200,
      yvalue: 300,
    },
    ...
  ]
  arr2 = [
    {
      parentNode: 1,
      childNode:3,
    },
    ...
  ]
```

arr1 are have node's id and node's xy coordinate data.
and arr2 have link between node, parentNode to childNode.

i need to make new array for parentNode's  xy coordinate and childNode's xy coordinate data like this

```
arr3 = [
    {
      sourceX: 200,
      sourceY: 300,
      targetX: 500,
      targetY: 600,
  }
]
```

how can I make array like this?

Comment: Please try to iterate over `arr2` and for each object, use `.find(arr1...` for both props `parentNode` and `childNode` and store the result in the required format (ie, `sourceX`, `targetX`, etc). It is fairly simple. Are you able to share your current progress and require help in fixing any issues being faced? Please let us know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use a `map` function, and then lookup the joins.

```js
const joined = arr2.map(it=>{
  const parent = arr1.find(a=>a.nodeId === it.parentNode)
  const child = arr1.find(a=>a.nodeId === it.childNode)
  return {
     sourceX: parent.xvalue,
     sourceY: parent.yvalue,
     targetX: child.xvalue,
     targetY: child.yvalue,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The below may be one possible solution to achieve the desired objective:

**Code Snippet**

```js
const getNewArr = (ar1, ar2) => (
  ar2.map(                                        // iterate over 'ar2' 
    ({parentNode, childNode}) => {                // de-structure iterator for parentNode, childNode
      const {xvalue: sourceX, yvalue: sourceY} = ar1.find(
        ({nodeId}) => (nodeId === parentNode)     // match 'ar1' nodeId with parent
      ) ?? {xvalue: 'notFound', yvalue: 'notFound'};      // if no match found
      const {xvalue: targetX, yvalue: targetY} = ar1.find(
        ({nodeId}) => (nodeId === childNode)      // match 'ar1' nodeId with child
      ) ?? {xvalue: 'notFound', yvalue: 'notFound'};      // no match found
      return {sourceX, sourceY, targetX, targetY}
    }
  )
);

const arr1 = [
    {
      nodeId: 1,
      xvalue: 200,
      yvalue: 300,
    },
    { // the childNode must have a matching 'id'
      nodeId: 3,
      xvalue: 500,
      yvalue: 600,
    },
  ];
  
const arr2 = [
    {
      parentNode: 1,
      childNode: 3,
    }
  ];

console.log(getNewArr(arr1, arr2));
```

**Explanation**

Inline comments in the above code-snippet describe each step. For any further clarifications, please use comments below.

**EDIT**

Using `.map` and `.find` along with de-structuring and implicit `return`.

```
  ar2.map(
    ({parentNode, childNode}) => (
      {xvalue: sourceX, yvalue: sourceY} = ar1.find(
        ({nodeId}) => (nodeId === parentNode)     
      ) ?? {xvalue: 'notFound', yvalue: 'notFound'},
      {xvalue: targetX, yvalue: targetY} = ar1.find(
        ({nodeId}) => (nodeId === childNode)
      ) ?? {xvalue: 'notFound', yvalue: 'notFound'},
      {sourceX, sourceY, targetX, targetY}
    )
  )
```